# Why is the CBS App not showing in the Windows Store?

Tags: apps, store

I am trying to install the [CBS App](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/cbs/3d731f11-faa1-44e6-bfe3-3fb869f381e4) on my [Nokia Lumia 520](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_lumia_520-5322.php). It does't show up in the Windows Store. I do see [CBS News](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/cbs-news/2e76714f-8874-487b-ade2-0ead8a0fe1c6) and [CBS Local](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/cbs-local/6fc03717-bdf5-4e17-b557-dab047ec66a5).

My phone is only 800 x 480 resolution, which I suspect may be the issue, but the page for the app only says you must have Windows Phone 8.1, which I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app you have linked to is a Windows (8) store app, not a Windows Phone application (also not a universal app). Therefore you can only install this on your PC, not your phone.